# Is it safe to use non-Apple adapter to charge Apple devices?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ipad, mac

Is it safe to charge your apple devices with an international adapter with multiple slots like this one?

> **Travel Adapter, All in one Worldwide Power Adapter Travel Plug, Fast Charging USB Type C, Smart USB Ports, Auto Fuse, International Plug Converter AUS, EU, US, UK, 220 Countries, AC Power Wall Plug**
>
> [image]

My concern is that this non-Apple adapter seems to be very compact, whereas Apple adapters seem to be much bigger.

I have iPhone, iPad, Apple Watch and Apple MacBook Pro. So I plan to use the adapter to charge all of these devices, potentially at the same time.

[international adapter from Amazon](https://www.amazon.com.au/Worldwide-Charging-International-Converter-Countries/dp/B07SK7T3WQ/ref=asc_df_B07SK7T3WQ/?tag=googleshopmob-22&linkCode=df0&hvadid=341743199244&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=2222741653841185984&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9071791&hvtargid=pla-988128253592&psc=1)

Comment: Nothing that's not officially from Apple is recommended by Apple, but most adapters will work with Apple devices. Just the wire should be an official Apple wire.

Comment: What safety organizations have certified that adapter and why wouldn’t you use Apple adapters which handle all voltages and frequencies?

Comment: @bmike this is much cheaper and convenient (instead of carrying multiple chargers)

Comment: @EpicProgrammer - Ummm...The [MiFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) would contradict your first statement re:  recommended by Apple.  Secondly, what's an "official Apple wire?"

Comment: My MackBook Pro cost $5000 USD and my iPhone was $1500 USD and I would never use anything other then the official chargers that came with them. It's not worth the possible loss in any respect to use 3rd party chargers that are not officially supported!

Answer (score 4):

> Is it safe to use non-Apple adapter to charge Apple devices?

Possibly.

There's an old consumer's adage... *You get what you pay for* and it's especially true when dealing with (expensive) Apple gear.

You've listed a number of "specs" but specs mean nothing in terms of quality.  The question is, do you want to plug your $3,000 USD MacBook Pro, $800-$1000 USD iPhone and $500-$800 USD iPad into a *discount* 3rd party charger?

[Cheap chargers can wreak havoc on your expensive gear](https://youtu.be/-8nLuNJvvMY) - if you can't get a genuine Apple product, get an adapter that's MiFi certified - at least you know that they have gone through the effort and cost to become certified by Apple that their products are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I’m using an old LG adapter for my iPod touch right now and have been since I got the iPod touch for an early christmas present last year, so I think you should be fine.